# Updating from Document DB SDK (2.7.0) to Cosmos SDK (3.12.0)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are in a process of updating our service code to using Cosmos SDK 3.12.0 from DocumentDB SDK 2.7.0. Since a change will likely be huge, we would like to do it incrementally that will result in our service using both SDKs to access the same databases (one executable loading assemblies of both SDKs). Please let us know if that is supported or if you see any issues in doing so. Also, I couldn’t figure out how to do things in same ways with Cosmos SDK (e.g. specifying “enable cross partition query” in querying items – the query method in 2.7.0 takes FeedOptions as a parameter whereas the new one in 3.12.0 doesn’t). I found this wiki and some sample code but if you have more info/guidelines for converting from Document SDK to Cosmos SDK, please let me know.

Comment: It's unclear what the actual question is...

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use both DocumentDB sdk and cosmos sdk access the same databases.
In Cosmos SDK 3.12.0,there is no need to set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` true.just do something like this is ok:

```
    QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("select * from c");
    FeedIterator<JObject> feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<JObject>(queryDefinition);
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```